# How to width a column if table is inside page block > page block section > page block section item

Tags: visualforce

My apex:pageBlockTable  is inside pageblocksectionitem. and I am not able to specify the column width, can any one suggest the solution

```
    <apex:page standardController="Batch_Job__c" extensions="AvailabilityCheckController" tabStyle="Line_Availability__c" cache="true">
  <apex:form id="avalForm">
    <apex:SectionHeader title="Line Availability Check"/>
    <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="avalPageBlock1">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit File" action="{!processCSVFile}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>

      <apex:actionRegion >
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Service Check Type" columns="1" collapsible="false" rendered="true" id="pageBlock1"> 
          <apex:selectRadio value="{!serviceCheckType}" >
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Line" itemLabel="Line Check"/> 
              <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Broadband" itemLabel="Broadband Check"/>
              <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Line&Broadband" itemLabel="Both Line & Broadband Checks"/>
              <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Broadband2" itemLabel="New Broadband Check" rendered="{!if($User.Email !='neil.jones@salesforce.com',false,true)}"/>
              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="lineAvailabilityRequests" />
          </apex:selectRadio>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>  
      </apex:actionRegion>

      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Upload File" columns="1" id="pageBlock2"> 
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" contentType="text/csv" accept="text/csv"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock id="avalPageBlock2">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit Rows" action="{!submitRows}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Details" id="lineAvailabilityRequests" columns="2"> 
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lineAvailabilityRequests}" var="lar"  columns="6" columnsWidth="10%,5%,5%,20%,30%,30%">
            <apex:column headerValue="Directory Number" >
              <apex:inputField value="{!lar.Directory_Number__c}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Post Code" width="5%" style="width:5%">
              <apex:inputField value="{!lar.Post_Code__c}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="House No" rendered="{!serviceCheckType!='Line'}" width="5%" style="width:5%">
              <apex:inputField value="{!lar.House_No__c}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="House Name" rendered="{!serviceCheckType!='Line'}" width="20%">
              <apex:inputField value="{!lar.House_Name__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Street" rendered="{!serviceCheckType!='Line'}" width="30%">
              <apex:inputField value="{!lar.Street__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Town" rendered="{!serviceCheckType!='Line'}" width="30%">
              <apex:inputField value="{!lar.Town__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
            <apex:inputText value="{!rowsToAdd}" size="1"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add Rows" action="{!addRows}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```